# Form Validation not working in Blazor 3.1

Tags: asp.net, blazor, blazor-server-side, blazor-validation

I am using EF to save data in DB and so far farm works fine and saves the data, but when i try to add validation to form it doesnt work & doesnt show any error message or save any data in database.

Example of working & non working code.

Below code without validation

`Employee.cs`

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

    namespace BlazorSPA1.Data
    {
        public class Employee
        {
            [MaxLength(50)]
            public string Id { get; set; }
    [MaxLength(50)]
            public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
            public string Department { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string Designation { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string Company { get; set; }
            [MaxLength(100)]
            public string City { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

`AddEmployee.razor`

```
@page "/addemployee"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IEmployeeService EmployeeService

<h2>Create Employee</h2>
<hr />
<form>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Name" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Department" class="control-label">Department</label>
                <input for="Department" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Department" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Designation" class="control-label">Designation</label>
                <input for="Designation" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Designation" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Company" class="control-label">Company</label>
                <input for="Company" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Company" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="City" class="control-label">City</label>
                <input for="City" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.City" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="@CreateEmployee" value="Save" />
                <input type="button" class="btn" @onclick="@Cancel" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

@code {

    Employee employee = new Employee();

    protected async Task CreateEmployee()
    {
        await EmployeeService.CreateEmployee(employee);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listemployees");
    }

    void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listemployees");
    }
}
```

Code which is not working after i made validation changes

`Employee.cs`

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
namespace BlazorSPA1.Data
{
    public class Employee
    {
        [MaxLength(50)]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string Department { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string Company { get; set; }
        [MaxLength(100)]
        public string City { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`AddEmployeeValidation.razor`

```
@page "/addemployeeValidation"
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
@inject IEmployeeService EmployeeService

<h2>Create Employee</h2>
<hr />
<EditForm Model="@employee" OnValidSubmit="@CreateEmployee">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name" class="control-label">Name</label>
                <input for="Name" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Name" />
                <ValidationMessage For="@(()=> employee.Name)" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Department" class="control-label">Department</label>
                <input for="Department" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Department" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Designation" class="control-label">Designation</label>
                <input for="Designation" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Designation" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Company" class="control-label">Company</label>
                <input for="Company" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.Company" />
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="City" class="control-label">City</label>
                <input for="City" class="form-control" @bind="@employee.City" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
                <input type="button" class="btn" @onclick="@Cancel" value="Cancel" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</EditForm>

@code {

    Employee employee = new Employee();

    protected async Task CreateEmployee()
    {
        await EmployeeService.CreateEmployee(employee);
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listemployees");
    }


    void Cancel()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("listemployees");
    }
}
```

I am using below code example show in this example https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/visual-studio-extension-for-blazor-spa-with-ef-core-3-1/

When i add validation code, it open Add Employee page but nothing happens no validation message no form submit even no data is save in database. not sure where issue is

Answer (score 7):

I had made a tiny mistake which went un-noticed, Validation started working when i changed the input type to `submit`

```
 <input type="button" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
```

Correct

```
   <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" />
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I used **OnSubmit**="OnCreate" which is wrong.
The correct one to fire validation, is **OnValidSubmit**="OnCreate"